# Concatenating dynamic column name to table - Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to create lists of data using dynamic columns, fetching the column name and appending it to the table.

Here is the problem as this step is throwing error:

**Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Table and Text.**

**Details:**

**Operator=&**
**Left=[Table]**

**Right=Test1**

Code:

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Sivakumar A\Desktop\Power BI\test1.xlsx"), null, true),
Sheet2_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet2",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet2_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Test1", type text}, {"Test2", Int64.Type}, {"Test3", Int64.Type}, {"Test4", Int64.Type}}),
#"Col Names" = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
#"Generate" = List.Generate(() => [i=-1,x= Table.FromList(#"Col Names",Splitter.SplitByNothing())],
each [i]<List.Count(#"Col Names"),
each [
i=[i]+1,
x=#"Promoted Headers"&#"Col Names"{i}

],
each [x])
in
Generate
```

I need to extract the column names and append it to the talble and execute in loop

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Like the error says, `#"Promoted Headers"` is a table and `#"Col Names"{i}` is a string like `"Test1"`. I can't tell what you're expecting to get with this operation or what your final result is supposed to be (why append columns from a table back onto a table that already contains that column?).

Comment: @AlexisOlson thanks for reply, Issue resolved, please check answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirement is to append the column names dynamically to the table using list.generate and generate the list of values out of it.

I was able to resolve the issue using Double Quotes 3 times.

```
"Table.Distinct(Table.FromList(#"&"""Sheet2 (2)"""&"["&#"Col Names"{i}&"], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error))"
```